# conditional lambda function from a list? pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

[image]

I would like to find the average age of people who have a dog using a lambda function,

and so far I have made this code

`pets['age'].mean(lambda x: x in pets['pets'] == 'dog')`

... but it keeps giving me a value error.....
help would be very appriciated!

Comment: What number is expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need `age` with dog and possible another values filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
out = df.loc[df['pets'].apply(lambda x: 'dog' in x), 'age'].mean()
print (out)
46.75
```

If need `age` with only dog :

```
out = df.loc[df['pets'].apply(lambda x: x[0] == 'dog'), 'age'].mean()

out = df.loc[df['pets'].str[0] == 'dog', 'age'].mean()
print (out)
55.333333333333336
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the job also without any lambda function.
One of possible solutions is:

```
df.explode('pets').query('pets == "dog"').age.mean()
```